# Data about indian businessmen

Tags: business, india

I am doing a social network analysis of Indian politicians and Businessmen.
I found the biodata of Indian politicians on Indian parliament websites.
Are there any datasets / sites giving the same for famous businessmen / company directors like Vijay Mallya or Naveen Jindal?